# assign the previous or next element of a list

Tags: java

```
public void nextElement() {
    //assign next element
    if (current != playlist.size() - 1)
        current++;
    else {
        current = 0;
    }
}

public void prevElement() {
    //assign previous element
    if (current == 0)
        current = playlist.size() -1;
    else {
        current--;
    }
}
```

I have a simple variable current and want it to increase or decrease when i call these methods, but when current = 1 and i call prevElement() it is set to 2 and I simply dont get why, does anyone see it? Kapuetze

Comment: are you sure that your'e calling `prevElement`, not `nextElement`?

Comment: debugging should help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have created same methods of your code and iterated multiple times and did not see any error. Can u have nested or complex calls of these methods in somewhere in your code.

> ```
>     NEXTPrev np = new NEXTPrev();
> ```

```
    np.nextElement();
    np.prevElement();
    np.nextElement();
    np.nextElement();
    np.nextElement();
    np.nextElement();
    np.nextElement();
    np.prevElement();
    np.nextElement();
    np.nextElement();
    np.nextElement();
    np.nextElement();

    np.nextElement();
    np.nextElement();
    np.nextElement();
    np.nextElement();
    np.nextElement();
    np.nextElement();
    np.nextElement();
    np.nextElement();
    np.prevElement();


public class NEXTPrev {

    private int current = 0;

    private final ArrayList playlist;

    public NEXTPrev() {
        playlist = new ArrayList();
        populateArraylist();
    }

    public void populateArraylist() {
        playlist.add("a");
        playlist.add("a");
        playlist.add("a");
        playlist.add("a");
        playlist.add("a");
    }

    public void nextElement() {
        //assign next element
        if (current != playlist.size() - 1) {
            current++;
        } else {
            current = 0;
        }
        printCurr("n");
    }

    public void prevElement() {
        //assign previous element
        if (current == 0) {
            current = playlist.size() - 1;
        } else {
            current--;
        }
        printCurr("p");
    }


   public void printCurr(String str){
       System.out.println("Current. "+str+":" + current);
   }
}


the out put:
Current. n:1
Current. p:0
Current. n:1
Current. n:2
Current. n:3
Current. n:4
Current. n:0
Current. p:4
Current. n:0
Current. n:1
Current. n:2
Current. n:3
Current. n:4
Current. n:0
Current. n:1
Current. n:2
Current. n:3
Current. n:4
Current. n:0
Current. n:1
Current. p:0
```

n->next and p-> previous method calls

Maybe something rather than here in your code is wrong

Comment: In case anyone will read this, I accidently reset current in another method I was calling. Both methods work just fine, as burhancerit already tested.